# Proper Stack Exchange site to ask about: suggesting films by some topic

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have one question about **suggesting films by some topic** asked [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110031/searching-for-films-by-contents-about-challenges-of-seeing-the-world-as-your-mir), which is recognized off-topic there, so I like to know which Stack Exchange site I can ask on. The question is like this:

I *have* one discussion with one friend about most things that I am afraid of in a relationship, so I answered her like this:

[image]

And I found another question, and that is:

> So by your answer to your question, I like to know what if the
> relation by others be assumed to yourself (others be your mirror!)

So I read somewhere the [love is projecting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UkX0CZM2qo) of the most beautiful things inside of yourself to another body, and think this topic is an interesting field, and by googling [**the mirror feeling and world**](https://www.google.com/search?q=mirror%20feeling%20and%20world&sxsrf=ALeKk01hxJZR_7z-VFvEO0Ku7nmcGYKOYw:1594935222489&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy3IDb3NLqAhXGsaQKHUs3BOcQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw) found interesting results which bring me this idea that there must be explained in the movie industry and the most affording things could see the negative feeling of yourself in this system, or maybe seeing of hidden feeling of yourself by this transparent system!!, but I think this could be one level of this kind system and would upgrade to another level.

So I like to see this feeling progress by viewing the world and relation like as a mirror universe, how much can go deeper (have it in relation, working by animals, etc ...), I think this kind of seeing the world must have some damage on the viewer person by lack of a controlling system (like when people scene with a love period of their life!) and have had its limitation that creates some disaster like [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) and ...  but could have some extra gift like seeing different angles of the world hologram and find some new knowledge (like experiencing new feeling for humans disgusted [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4c1lqFXHvqI)), enjoying scenes (!!!), problem of experiencing many feelings and computing the big data in that condition and ...

So I like to see some aspect of these viewpoints in serials or films, and asked here to know more about that, maybe the topic could be:

**Challenges of seeing the world as your mirror**, or **what results could be found by seeing the world as your mirror?**

Also, it is my first question in this Stack Exchange  site, so if you like guide me to ask better if it is necessary.

Comment: No such site exists, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but I don't think that such a site exists on Stack Exchange.  The site where you posted your original question, [Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com), comes as close as I can think of, but as you've shown, it's off-topic there.